# Problem using branched path tracing with ati 1050 card

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, hardware

Every time I use branched path tracing in cycles rendering, I get an error message of cuda failed. I have an atI  1050ti nvidia card. It works fine with path tracing. For branched path I always need to switch to cpu rendering or it will error out on any scene. Is there anything I can do to make this card work right?